# "Look up & data detectors" not working in Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft PowerPoint, and Google Chrome PDF

Tags: macos, ms-office, google-chrome, adobe, look-up

I'm learning English as a foreign language, so I often need to look up words by force-clicking. Most of the time, this brings up a window that shows the dictionary definition of that word. However, this feature does not work in Adobe Acrobat, Microsoft PowerPoint, and Google Chrome (when a PDF is opened and is the active tab). When I force-click, nothing happens. There is also no "Look up" option in the menu when right-clicking on the word.

Does this feature require special effort from the application developers? Is there anything I can do to fix this issue, or is it something that only the application developers can do?

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, Google Chrome 88.0.4324.96, newest version of Office and Adobe Acrobat.